# How to get current time while streaming mp3 using NAudio?

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

I have a code to stream mp3 from url. I want to show the current time of the mp3 player in UI. I tried it using `WaveOut.GetPosition`, but it couldn't work for me.
How can I do that?

***My code:***

```
do
 {
    //..codes to get url stream,to create BufferedWaveProvider

    int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
    provider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
    if (provider.BufferedDuration.Seconds > 2 && waveOut == null)
    {
       waveOut = new WaveOut();
       waveOut.Init(provider);
       waveOut.Play();
    }
    if (waveOut != null)
    {
       currentTime = (int)(waveOut.GetPosition() * 1d / AvgBytesPerSec);
    }
 }
 while (bytesRead > 0 || waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing);
```

Comment: What type is `provider`?

Comment: `provider` is BufferedWaveProvider, `waveOut` is WaveOut. If you need, I can put the whole code.

Comment: How is it not working?  Is it playing back the audio at all?

Comment: It returns too large numbers. I was thinking it shows the read position from the provider but it doesn't. Also `BufferedWaveProvider` is derived from `CircularBuffer`, so it cycles in itself and can't contain a position like normal streams or buffers.. I can't find out the right formula to calculate the current time using `GetPosition`. So I am currently using Timer.Tick which is running only in the case `WaveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing` to calculate the time position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only change you need to make to your code is to use `waveOut.OutputWaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond` instead of the `AvgBytesPerSec` property you are currently using.  The `IWavePosition` interface (which is what you are actually using here) "thinks" in hardware terms, so if you are using a format that has to be converted before the hardware can use it, the hardware byte rate will be different than your source byte rate.

Note that the position returned by `GetPosition()` is only since playback was last started.  If `waveOut.Stop()` is called, the position is reset to 0 when playback is started again.  Mapping the position to the source is up to the caller (which is really simple; just track where you last started playback on the source and add it to the position returned.  Buffering makes it more complicated, but still completely doable).

I wrote the original IWavePosition interface & implementations for NAudio. It works great in the project I built it for. :)

Comment: It works well. My value the `AvgBytesPerSec` was `Mp3WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond` constructed by using `Mp3Frame` properties. I think the difference is decompressing the frame. Because the length of bytes is increased when a frame is decompressed. Thanks for help @ioctILR.

Answer (score 1):

did you try the property current time and property position?

```
mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader("example.mp3");

waveOut.Init(mp3Reader);

waveOut.Play();

// reposition to five seconds in
mp3Reader.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0);
```

so `mp3Reader.CurrentTime` should give you what you need I think

Hope this will help you

Comment: but i need to stream it from url source. i know Mp3FileReader only works for saved files. is there a solution for streaming?

Comment: from codeplex `BufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration`,https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/BufferedWaveProvider.cs, by browsing the code, you might find a way, also you can edit the source code

Comment: There is so much dependent classes in the source code, but I will try it. Thanks for the suggestion.